# Test for differentiability of a 2-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f=\begin{cases}(x+y)\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2 &y\ne 0\\ \frac{\pi x}{2} &y=0\end{cases}$$

Test $f$ for differentiability on the point $(0,0)$.

Okay, I found the partial derivatives at that point:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$$

Now I find this limit:

$$\begin{cases}x=\rho\sin\varphi\\ y=\rho\cos\varphi\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{align}\lim_{\rho\to 0}\frac{\Delta f}{\rho} &=\lim_{\rho\to 0}\frac{\rho(\sin\varphi+\cos\varphi)\arctan\left(\frac{\cos^2\varphi}{\sin^2\varphi}\right)-0}{\rho}\\ &=(\sin\varphi+\cos\varphi)\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\arctan^2\varphi}\right)\ne 0\end{align}$$

Does this mean the function is not differentiable at point  $(0,0)$? What about the second part, when  $y=0$? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around these functions that are divided on two parts, like if-statements. How to test for differentiability on these cases.

Thank you!

Edit: Fixed mistake pointed out by A.Γ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if the function were differentiable at the origin then the directional derivative along any (normalized) direction $h=(h_1,h_2)$ would necessarily be 
$$
\nabla f(0,0)^Th=\frac{\pi}{2}h_1.
$$
Now, test what happens along the line $x+y=0$.

P.S. Your calculation of the directional derivative does not seem sound: you mixed up $\cos$ and $\sin$ in $\arctan$ and then, how did you get $\phi$ from $\arctan(\tan^2\phi)$?